# What license is used for the content of Bitcoin.org?

Tags: websites, license, bitcoin.org

What license is used for the content of [Bitcoin.org](http://www.bitcoin.org)?

In the footer of the website we can find that the website is licensed under the [MIT license](http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php), but the MIT licensed is used only for code, right? I also have looked at [Legal disclaimer](https://bitcoin.org/en/legal) and the [Frequently Asked Questions section](https://bitcoin.org/en/faq), but I couldn't find the answer.

**Under which license is the content of Bitcoin.org available? CC BY 3.0? CC BY 4.0? MIT?**

Answer (score 3):

I've posted this question on [Bitcoin.org GitHub repository](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.org/issues/817#issuecomment-91542344) and I've got the answer.

According to @harding, from Github, the content of Bitcoin.org is commonly licensed under MIT, only not when specified. [Here is his full answer](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.org/issues/817#issuecomment-91542344):

> the MIT license, as stated. You can also check the COPYING file in the repository, which says;
>
> The intellectual property rights in the files are owned by the respective authors. Some of the files can be licensed under MIT License (MIT) available on http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT or other licenses. Appropriate licensing information can be found in the header of the file or in the folder containing the file.
>
> In general, text files have the license information near the top and image files have the license information in a file in the directory.

@saivan commented:

> [FAQ] certain pictures listed on the page are not MIT licensed (see the COPYING file here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.org/tree/master/img/faq). This being said, although I am not a lawyer, I think you can easily use screenshots like this without much copyright issues

Thanks for your replies, guys, but I will elect this one as the best answer cause this is the response I really wanted.

Answer (score 2):

> but MIT licensed is used only for code, right?

Typically, but it's also used for documentation too.

As far as I can tell, all of the content on bitcoin.org is MIT licensed. [Source.](http://bitcoin.org/COPYING)

Comment: Thank you, but I need a precise answer (I mean, linking to an official document on Bitcoin.org that tells me which is the license).

Comment: @FernandoPaladini I've linked to the document that I based my opinion on.

Answer (score 1):

The github repo for the site has this 'COPYING' licence terms:
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.org/blob/master/COPYING

`The intellectual property rights in the files are owned by the respective
authors. Some of the files can be licensed under MIT License (MIT) available on
http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT or other licenses. Appropriate licensing
information can be found in the header of the file or in the folder containing
the file.`

TL;DR; It's MIT, except where it is not